# Is there any way to stop on hydration React App in Cypress?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cypress

I'm testing React Application that  pre rendered with Next.js.
My application have [two pass](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/#two-pass-rendering) rendering: loading screen and actual app screen.
So I wrote cypress test like this:

```
// using @testing-library/cypress
it('Some of my tests', () => {
  cy.visit('http://localhost:4000/annotation/edit');
  // bypass next.js router alert outside of my app
  cy.get('div#__next').findByRole('alert', { name: /loading/i });
  cy.findByRole('form', { name: /sign in form/i }).within(() => {
    cy.findByRole('textbox', { name: /account name/i }).type('...');
    cy.findByRole('textbox', { name: /email/i }).type('...');
    cy.findByLabelText(/password/i).type('...');
    cy.findByRole('button', { name: /sign in/i }).click();
  });
  cy.findByRole('progressbar');
});
```

But it sometimes success, sometimes fail by skipping the first screen. I checked with cypress video and browser runner, there was loading screen and transition to actual app. But Cypress couldn't capture it. The alert in loading screen has accesible name `/loading` is not conditional, always same. I think Cypress is unstable at rendering.

Is there any way to make a throttle in some steps or capture current DOM?

Comment: Do you need to wait until the sign in form is on the screen before proceeding?

Comment: @ksav yes, I want to check loading screen spec.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60063879/how-to-wait-for-element-to-be-visible

Comment: @ksav I think that's a different situation. Problem here is the rendering already done. So the `.should('be.visible')` will not work. I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, you are adopting this pattern of code to give the user a better experience during loading

```js
const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
  setHasMounted(true);
}, []);

if (!hasMounted) {
  return <Alert>Loading</Alert>  // compiled on the server
}

return <SignInForm>
```

Seems the flakyness is because the window of time for the loading alert is very small.

One way to handle it might be to hand control of `setHasMounted` to Cypress.

```js
const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (window && window.Cypress) {
    window.Cypress.setHasMounted = setHasMounted   // now the test can call this
  } else {
    setHasMounted(true);
  }
}, []);

if (!hasMounted) {
  return <Alert>Loading</Alert>  // compiled on the server
}

return <SignInForm>
```

**Test**

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:4000/annotation/edit');

cy.get('div#__next')
  .findByRole('alert', { name: /loading/i })
  .then(() => Cypress.setHasMounted(true))

cy.findByRole('form'...
```

Comment: You understood correct. I wish there's better solution that decouple my app with Cypress... isn't this possible?

Comment: It think it can also be done if you `setTimeout(() => setHasMounted(true), 10)` in the `useEffect()`, then Cypress `cy.clock()` & `cy.tick(10)` can control the timeout. But it's dubious if that is a better way